# FragmentStateAdapter not recreating currentFragment after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have a FragmentStateAdapter as the adapter of a ViewPager2.

```kotlin
class DefaultFragmentStateAdapter(fragment: Fragment) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

    var items = listOf<Fragment>()
       set(value) {
           field = value
           notifyDateSetChanged()
       }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = items[position]
}
```

The adapters item can change depending on the date a user has selected, so it needs to be dynamical.
What happens is that after I call `adapter.items = {new_fragments}` current fragment is not reloaded, only after I go to one of the last pages in the ViewPager and return to the first page can I see the updated fragment.
The current fragment does not update when `notifyDataSetChanged` is called.

How can I manage to update current displayed fragment?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had to override the following two methods...

```kotlin
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return items[position].id
}

override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean = items.any { it.id == itemId }
```

... to make it work!

Comment: return items[position].id expects a long value

Comment: I don't know why but overriding getItemId() and containsItem() makes the fragments load twice.

Comment: I need to understand why too.

Comment: This is the real solution to Viewpager2 weird behaviour. In my case as I has no usable ids in my data I created fake ones and update those ids every time the data was updated.

Comment: If you want to use a attribute as ID you could do something like : items.get(position).getId().hashCode().toLong()

Comment: override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long { with some unique hashcode of each page - solves the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The best way that I found was [setUserVisibleHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean))

add this to your fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // load data here
    }else{
       // fragment is no longer visible
    }
}
```

Comment: Page limit MUST be bigger than 1 as per the documentation, else it throws an exception!

Comment: Sorry, what was working when I used 5, here is the update

Comment: @JamaldinSabirjanov, it's not clear to me why overriding the Fragment's `setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser:)` method will resolve the issue in `FragmentStateAdapter`. Still, out of curiosity, I did override it and observed that it's never called before or after the `FragmentStateAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call. Please explain why or how this fixes the issue. I noticed also when experimenting with this method that's marked as deprecated. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)).