# How to update fragmentStateAdapter after a bottomSheet dismiss

Tags: android, fragmentstateadapter

I have this **fragmentStateAdapter** which holds some of my **Cards** in order to swipe among them:

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(activity: AppCompatActivity, var items: ArrayList<Helpers.Card>, private val saveToDb: Boolean) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {
override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.count()
var fragment:CardItemFragment?=null
override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment{
    fragment =CardItemFragment(position, saveToDb ,this) //.newInstance( items[position ].getSaveString())
    return fragment as CardItemFragment
}}
```

and the **CardItemFragement** is:

```
class CardItemFragment(val position:Int, val saveToDb: Boolean, val isCardMine: Boolean,val adapter: ScreenSlidePagerAdapter) : Fragment() {
    lateinit var cardView1: ConstraintLayout
    lateinit var crdNameTB1: TextView
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, container, false)
    cardView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.cardView1)
    crdNameTB1= v.findViewById(R.id.crdNameTB1)
    return v
  }
```

Then I can update the **Card** inside the **fragementStateAdapter** like this:

```
 fun updateCard(): Bitmap? {
     crdNameTB1.text = .....
}
```

That's works fine and I can swipe among my Cards, but when I change the value of "name" attribute of my **Card** via a **bottom sheet** and when I dismiss the **BottomSheet** I use this code to refresh the **fragmentSatateAdapter**:

```
 MainActivity.galleryPagerAdapter?.fragment ?.updateCard()
```

I set **MyActivity** as **companion object** to reach it anywher.

When this code executed, I got the **fragment** not null object but the **updateCard** gives me null objects
1what is the problem and how can I overcome this and update the shown **Card**?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer by overriding the following methods in order to make the Adapter run

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {return items[position].id}


override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean = items.any { it.id == itemId }
```

the answer post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959705/fragmentstateadapter-not-recreating-currentfragment-after-notifydatasetchanged)