# How to recreate or refresh fragment while swiping ViewPager2 tabs

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I have a viewpager2 with FragmentStateAdapter() adapter inside it. I also have a tab layout with 4 tabs. I use a single fragment for all tab. that is named AllOrdersTab.
in my architecture I just send different value to load different API data to AllOrdersTab fragment.
when each tab layout is selected , a fragment created and works fine for the first time for all 4 fragments. after that if I swipe back to previous tab it is not created or refreshed again.
I want to recreate the fragment or a way to call API again when swiping between tabs. I also read this page.

[FragmentStateAdapter not recreating currentFragment after notifyDataSetChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959705/fragmentstateadapter-not-recreating-currentfragment-after-notifydatasetchanged)

I tried to do this. so I decided to create 4 instance of Allorderstab() fragment. but never work for me because I guess hash codes of fragments are same.

ViewPager2 Adapter:

```
class ViewPagerOrdersAdapter(fm: FragmentManager,val listFragments:MutableList<Fragment>, viewlifecycler: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, viewlifecycler)
{

    override fun getItemCount(): Int
    {
        return listFragments.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        val args = Bundle()

        when (position) {
            1 -> {
                args.putString("KEY_ID", "inProgress")
                listFragments[position].arguments = args
                return listFragments[position]
            }
            2 -> {
                args.putString("KEY_ID", "cancel")
                listFragments[position].arguments = args
                return listFragments[position]
            }
            3 ->
            {
             args.putString("KEY_ID","deliver")
                listFragments[position].arguments=args
                return listFragments[position]
            }
            else -> {
                args.putString("KEY_ID", "all")
                listFragments[position].arguments = args
                return listFragments[position]
            }
        }

    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return   listFragments[position].hashCode().toLong()
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {

        return listFragments.find {it.id.hashCode().toLong() == itemId } != null
    }


}
```

Here I created 4 instance of Allorderstab() Fragment.

Set ViewPager2 Adapter
MainFragment:

```
    val fragments:MutableList<Fragment> = mutableListOf(Allorderstab(), Allorderstab(), Allorderstab(), Allorderstab())

    vp.setAdapter(ViewPagerOrdersAdapter(this.childFragmentManager,fragments, lifecycle))
```

AllOrderstab Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
 val bundle = arguments
       bundle?.let {
           val myStatus = bundle.getString("KEY_ID")
           myStatus?.let{
               //getting history of each tab orders - calling API
               myviewModel.getOrdersHistory(tempTn,myStatus)
           }
       }
}
```

All in all I don't know how to refresh while swiping between tabs . if I have a single fragment for all 4 tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who wasted a day for this problem like me , wanting to call API each time for refreshing data, Move your code to onResume function. fortunately it is run each time your fragment visible.

AllOrderstab Fragment:

```
override fun onResume() {
    val bundle = arguments
    bundle?.let {
        val myStatus = bundle.getString("KEY_ID")
        myStatus?.let{
            //getting history of all orders
            myviewModel.getOrdersHistory(tempTn,myStatus)
        }
    }

    super.onResume()
}
```

Comment: Hey can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70593277/11560810)

Comment: @vivekmodi I saw your problem in YouTube link. unfortunately I don't work with paging3 library yet. maybe there is a bug or something that is related to lifecycles. Here I used viewpager2 (FragmentStateAdapter) with Tablayout.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 different instances of the same tab. If you need to refresh the tabs everytime the user navigates to your tab you need to add a `PageChangeListener` to your tabs view. Then whenever you change the page you need to notify the fragment that it has come to foreground you can do so by calling a method on `Allorderstab` class and then refreshing the data from this method.

Comment: Thanks but your solution was not suitable and compatible for use with an FragmentStateAdapter adapter for Viewpager2. I think it interferes with MVVM architecture.

Comment: @NimaAzhd It might not be best for your use case but it does not violate the MVVM pattern.